# Make a div rotate 180 deg when changing scroll direction

Tags: javascript, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I'm making a webpage where I have this illustration traveling down the page, when I change the scroll direction I want it to rotate 180 degrees to match the direction of scrolling. Can't find anything on the internet to help me write this line of JS. I'm pretty new to js and want to learn it through doing.

Comment: Can you show us your current code? (Or if not, what kind of HTML element is the "illustration", an <img> maybe?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with first determine the scroll direction, then whenever the scroll changes:

```js
let direction = null;
let oldScroll = 0;
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  // print "false" if direction is down and "true" if up
 if(this.oldScroll > this.scrollY) {
   if(direction !== "up") {
     document.getElementById("box").style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
   }
   direction = "up"
 } else {
   if(direction !== 'down'){
     document.getElementById("box").style.transform = "";
   }
   direction = "down";
 }
  this.oldScroll = this.scrollY;
}
```

```css
.box{
  transition: all 2s;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
.container{
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="box"></div>
</div>
```